# Adding content to same line if line contains a string

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have `$file`, `$key` for match and `$string` to add.
If there is a certain line in `$file` that **contains** `$key`, add `$string` to end of the line.
For example:
`$key="b"`, `$string="z"`

`$file` contains:

```
a
b
c
```

New `$file` contains:

```
a
b z
c
```

How can I do it in the simplest way in PowerShell?
Note! `$file` is an actual file and not some array in the program

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to iterate over each line and check whether the line contains the key:

```
$newContent = Get-Content $file | Foreach {
    if ($_ -like "*$key*")
    {
        "$_ $string"
    }
    else
    {
        $_
    }
} 
$newContent | Set-Content $file
```

Comment: Ok, and what if `$file` contains the following:
`a
b c d e 
f`

and I want to add "z" to end of the line that contains `$key="b"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$file="C:\temp\report.csv"
$Newfile="C:\temp\report2.csv"
$KeyToSearch="b"
$StringToAdd="z"

Get-Content $file | 
%{if ($_ -like "*$KeyToSearch*") {"$_ $StringToAdd" } else {$_}} | 
out-file -FilePath $Newfile -Append
```

Comment: Thx, what is the difference between using "out-file..." as you said, and "set-content..." and written in the answer before?

Comment: Not really difference you can use 2 solutions ;)